Literature for a supervised task on time series
I was introduced to the following project at my company.
We have $n$ time series coming from $n$ sensors. Each sensor has monitored a physical signal at a specific location. For each time series, a human has labeled time intervals during which a special event occurs (this event is recurrent, it is caused by a single underlying physical phenomenon, when the event occurs the time series has a characteristic shape which is visible to the naked eye). Note that the number of events may not be the same for different series.
The goal is to build a model so that, when an additional sensor is installed at a new location, the new time series is given as input to the model, which labels all the intervals during which the event occured.
The underlying machine-learning task does not seem very novel, hence I suspect that this task is well-known in the time series litterature.
The following keywords seem relevant: event detection, change-point detection, motif discovery.
However they do not exactly match with our specific task.
I'm looking for more relevant keywords, or pointers to some relevant literature which might be helpful for the task.
